# Importing SAP NetWeaver Summary Statement Data to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, netweaver

Hi I recently have been taking a deeper dive into Excel and I was thinking about how to automate a task that I have to do every month. Every month I update financial projections by manually entering in monthly expenses into a spreadsheet for each account.

I would like to find a way to pull data that I normally manually enter from SAP Netweaver and our inhouse website that lists salary charges to an Excel spreadsheet.

What do I need to learn to automate this repetitive task? I am not an expert in Computer Science by any means so if anyone has any suggestions on ways to solve this problem, topics to learn that would be helpful and/or online resources that would help me learn how to automate this data entry it would be greatly appreciated.

TL;DR I want to upload data from SAP to an Excel file where financial projections are kept so I don't have to manually enter the data in every month.

Comment: While I can sympathize with your problem, the focused FAQ-style of stackoverflow is not really an ideal place to start your search.

Comment: If you could point me in the direction of an answer, what I should learn to solve the problem or a resource that would be better than stack overflow it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: SAP is a big software company, so you should at least indicate the name of the concerned SAP software. But as said previously, Stack Overflow is not the primary place to ask, it's dedicated to precise questions, not to ask advices without describing very precisely as explained in the Help page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write some vba code to login into SAP and select necessary data, you need to develop custom function module on ABAP that will select it.

So it's much easier to write custom report with export to Excel. ABAP isn't very difficult to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at some of the query tools available within Netweaver. Transaction SQVI can be used to build a simple query involving one or more tables, from which the results (in ALV) can be exported to excel. Transaction SQ01, SQ02 and SQ03 can be used for the same, but are a bit more involved.